# Why do two CPUs work when I am only working with one process?

Tags: python, cpu-usage

I'm running a script like

```
def test0():
    start = time()
    for i in range(int(1e8)):
        i += 1
    print(time() - start)
```

When I run this on my machine which has 4 CPUs I get the following trace for CPU usage using the Ubuntu 20.04 system monitor.

[image]

In the image you can see I ran two experiments separated by some time. But in each experiment, the activity of 2 of the CPUs peaks. Why?

Comment: also see the processes which is running behind

Comment: Your script is not the only thing running on the system. There's also your terminal emulator, and lots of background processes.

Comment: Since the script is printing lots of output, it's causing the terminal emulator to update the display. The script is running on one CPU, the terminal is on another.

Comment: @Barmar there's only one line printed out. Why would that take up 100% of another cpu?

Comment: Because, the CPU usage is not just from your python script. There are other processes running on you device.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal yes, although, if I'm to believe that 2 CPU's will be used to full capacity everytime I run one process in Python, I'll feel like I got a bit ripped off by the quad-core marketing. Right?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the print line was in the loop.

Comment: No, you were not ripped off. There are many ways that multiple cores can be used effectively: 1) A database application runs in one core while the DB server is in another. 2) There are libraries like numpy that have the option to use multiple cores. 3) You can run multiple applications at the same time.

Comment: @Barmar it was a joke :) but the info us useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems normal to me. The process that is running your python code is not, at least by default, pinned to a specific core. This means that the process can be switched between different cores, which is what is happening in this case. Those spikes are not simultaneous, it indicates that the process was switched from one core to another.

On Linux, you can observe this using

```
watch -tdn0.5 ps -mo pid,tid,%cpu,psr -p 172810
```

where `172810` is PID of the python process (which you can get, for example, from the output of `top`)

If you want to pin the process to a particular core, you can use `psutils` in your code.

```
import psutil
p = psutil.Process()
p.cpu_affinity([0])   # pinning the process to cpu 0
```

Now, you should see only one core spiking. (but avoid doing this if you don't have a good reason for it).